# Replace html tag with another tag and then remove other tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a `textarea` where the user can edit some text, they are allowed to use html (I know all the users and trust them) Then the content of that textarea gets saved in a database. And after it gets printet into in element.

How do i replace all headings `<h1><h2><h3>`etc.. with `<b>`tags and then remove all tags that are different from `<b>`and `<p>`

The user input gets stored in a variable like this:

```
column_content = $('.dialog_editor').val();
```

Comment: what should happen to the content inside those tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
var column_content =
    '<h1>Test 1</h1>\n' +
    '<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>\n' +
    '<h2>Test 2</h2>\n' +
    '<input type="button" onclick="alert(&quot;missed me&quot;)" value="Click">\n' +
    '<a href="javascript://">keep this</a>\n' +
    '<h3>Test 3</h3>\n' +
    'unwrapped text';

var $temp = $("<div></div>").html(column_content);

$temp.find("h1, h2, h3").each(function () {
    $(this).wrapInner("<b></b>").children().insertAfter(this);
});
$temp.find(":not(b, p)").each(function () {
    $(this).contents().insertAfter(this);
    $(this).remove();
});
console.log($temp.html());
/*
<b>Test 1</b>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<b>Test 2</b>

keep this
<b>Test 3</b>
unwrapped text
*/
```

Comment: what about other tags?

Comment: I think all other tags except `b` and `p` are to be removed.

Comment: Nice solution, but i can see i havn't been clear enough, i dont want the content of others tags to be removed like the a tag does in this one, i just want it to be printet without any tag :)

Comment: I see, using the `.contents().unwrap()` from the other answer will be sufficient.

Comment: Note: I've revised the answer slightly so that it also removes empty tags.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$('.dialog_editor').change(function () {
    var column_content = $('.dialog_editor').val();

    var $temp = $('<div />',{html: column_content});

    //process headers
    $temp.find(':header').wrapInner('<b />').contents().unwrap();

    $temp.find('*:not(p, b)').contents().unwrap();

    $('#html').html($temp.html());
    $('#text').text($temp.html());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CQcS9/)

Comment: Good awnser mate, im sure a lot of people would use thism is just personally like Salmans awnser a little better, but thank you for your time :)